# Extracting Instagram comments from every user post

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, data-mining, instagram-api

I would like to extract every comment for 1000+ user posts.
So far, I have experimented with an Instagram scraper tool ((https://github.com/realsirjoe/instagram-scraper), but have not succeeded with the loop.

```
#pip install igramscraper
from igramscraper.instagram import Instagram
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
instagram = Instagram()

post1 = instagram.get_media_comments_by_id('732428342682579959', 1000)
list=[]
for a in post1['comments']:
    dict={}
    dict['Comments'] = comment.text
    list.append(dict)
pd.DataFrame(list)
```

The above code allows me to get 1000 comments from a single post.
How do I do the same for every other post?
I tried to store post media IDs in a list and then loop over the list, but it didn't work.

```
#extracting all the media posts
instagram.media = instagram.get_medias("cocacola", 1500)
c = [cc.__dict__ for cc in instagram.media]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(c)
df
#storing the media id into a list called "l"
l=[]
for a in df['link']:
    d={}
    d["Media_ID"]=get_media_id(a)
    l.append(d)
#loop the media IDs to extract all instagram comments
list2=[]
i=0
for a in l:
    dict2={}
    dict2['Comments']=instagram.get_media_comments_by_id(l[i]['Media_ID'], 10000)
    sleep(2)
    list2.append(dict2)
    list3=[]
    for a in dict2['Comments']:
        dict3={}
        dict3['Comments'] = comment.text
        list3.append(dict3)
    i=i+1
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: did you finally manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The function get_medias returns a ['igramscraper.model.media.Media'](https://github.com/realsirjoe/instagram-scraper/blob/master/igramscraper/model/media.py) class

I use this function to extract the information from the media class and then do loop the comments list:

```
def check_comments(insta):  
  
  sleep(2) 

  medias = instagram.get_medias(insta, 5)  

  # find all attrs here https://github.com/realsirjoe/instagram-scraper/blob/master/igramscraper/model/media.py
  for media in medias:    
    print(media.comments)
    print(type(media.comments))
```

Then you can use like this:

```
check_comments('9gag')
```

This will return a list with all comments from the selected media.